# jquery get() does not return any response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I actually try to load a php script and get some return values.

I tried the following code: 
http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FA39VK30JU3U

It does the GET request correctly as i can see with firebug. 
But it never shows me any response with the alert box.

I have also tried the following code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "test.php",
        dataType: "html"
    }).done(function (res) {
        // Your `success` code
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("AJAX call failed: " + textStatus + ", " + errorThrown + " - " +jqXHR.status);
    });
```

This returns ERROR undefined code 0

I hope someone see the mistake. 
Thanks!

**Update:**

This is my original code:

```
$.get( "test.php", function( data ) {
      alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
    });
```

This also does not work!

This is my test.php:

```
<?php

echo "Hellllooouuu";

?>
```

Comment: The alert is in the `fail` handler so it'll show only when the request fails, no?

Comment: If there is a response, then the .done() function will be run. You haven't written anything in that function. Put the alert in that function to get an alert, and you might get something out of this.

Comment: Go check your browser console for errors. (Pretty sure it will tell you that you can not load that external resource, because no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is set by the remote party.)

Comment: Pekka  @diaco  be carefull, the code which is posted here in the question is not the same as the one in the link!

CBroe i will check the console

Comment: @CBroe has the correct answer.

Comment: @Pekka but how can it be that the browser requests the website sucessfully as i can see in the firebug network section?

Comment: I guess it's because the browser has to actually make the request to see whether the response comes back with a CORS header that would permit the cross-domain request to be made.

Comment: So do i have to send the header from my test.php site to my javascript?

Comment: @CBroe you are right! it was the header. Thanks

Comment: `So do i have to send the header from my test.php site to my javascript?` No, the server has to do that.  You won't be able to get data from that domain through Ajax unless it sends the header. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy for why

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Try to use done callback, see this:**

http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FA3BI1524HTC

**About jqXHR Object:**

> As of jQuery 1.5, all of jQuery's Ajax methods return a superset of
> the XMLHTTPRequest object. This jQuery XHR object, or "jqXHR",
> returned by $.get() implements the Promise interface, giving it all
> the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise (see Deferred
> object for more information). The jqXHR.done() (for success),
> jqXHR.fail() (for error), and jqXHR.always() (for completion, whether
> success or error; added in jQuery 1.6) methods take a function
> argument that is called when the request terminates.
>
> The Promise interface also allows jQuery's Ajax methods, including
> $.get(), to chain multiple .done(), .fail(), and .always() callbacks
> on a single request, and even to assign these callbacks after the
> request may have completed. If the request is already complete, the
> callback is fired immediately.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/